# liblastfm compilation error with g++

Tags: c++, c, linux, include, last.fm

I receive this compilation error when I try to compile my code:

```
/tmp/cc5InCzw.o: In function `Audiophile::lastfm_session()':
/media/Storage/Source Files/Audiophile/Scrobbling.cc:25: undefined reference to `LASTFM_init(char const*, char const*)'
/media/Storage/Source Files/Audiophile/Scrobbling.cc:27: undefined reference to `LASTFM_login(void*, char const*, char const*)'
/media/Storage/Source Files/Audiophile/Scrobbling.cc:48: undefined reference to `LASTFM_status(void*, char const**, int const**, char const**)'
/media/Storage/Source Files/Audiophile/Scrobbling.cc:51: undefined reference to `LASTFM_track_scrobble(void*, char*, char*, char*, long, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, _List**)'
/media/Storage/Source Files/Audiophile/Scrobbling.cc:54: undefined reference to `LASTFM_dinit(void*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have been trying to compile an audio program I've been making for Linux with the C library [liblastfm](http://liblastfm.sourceforge.net/). Here is the code for the file that holds my function for scrobbling. The username, password and API keys are changed to Xs.

```
#include "Audiophile.h"                                                            
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
#include <time.h>                                                                  
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
#include <string.h>                                                                
#include "clastfm.h"                                                            

void Audiophile::lastfm_session()                                                  
{                                                                                  

  scrobbling = true;                                                               

  void LASTFM_SESSION *s;                                                          

//    LASTFM_ALBUM_INFO *album;                                                    

//    LASTFM_ARTIST_INFO *artist;                                                  

//    LFMList *list = NULL,*i;                                                     


  const char *status = NULL;                                                       

  s = LASTFM_init("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",                             
                    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");                           

  int rv = LASTFM_login(s,"XXXXXXXXXXXXX","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");                        

  if(rv != 0)                                                                      
  {                                                                                
    cout << "\n\nAn error occurred when logining in!\n\n";                      
  }                                                                                

  unsigned int length = ((position_field / 6000000000) / 10000000000);             

  char* title = const_cast<char*>((playing_track.title()).c_str());                 

  char* album = const_cast<char*>((playing_track.album()).c_str());                 

  char* artist = const_cast<char*>((playing_track.artist()).c_str());              

  time_t start_time;                                                               

  time(&start_time);                                                               

  cout << "\n\nstart time: " << start_time << "\n\n";                              

  LASTFM_status(s,&status,NULL,NULL);                                              

  LASTFM_track_scrobble(s, artist, album, title, start_time, length,               
                        0, 0, NULL);                                               


  LASTFM_dinit(s);                                                                 

  scrobbling = false;                                                              

}
```

I include -lclastfm in my compile statement. It is this:

```
g++ -g -Wall main.cc Audiophile_GTK3.cc Menu_GTK3.cc Playlist_GTK3.cc Configuration_GTK3.cc Configuration.cc Audiophile.cc Metadata.cc Scrobbling.cc -std=c++0x -o audiophile `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0` $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0) $(pkg-config --libs --cflags taglib) -lclastfm -lconfig++ -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

I'm using Arch. I checked /usr/include and clastfm.h is there. I even tried adding clastfm.h to my program's main directory. That didn't work either. I'm using GStreamer 1.24 extensively in my code, which is pure C. Other than having to clarify a few enumerations, it's worked perfectly with g++. Could an enumeration-related issue be the reason those compilation errors are occurring?

I'll provide the github to my code once I update it if that will help. Not knowing how to do version numbering is the only reason it's not updated (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not *compiler errors*; your C code is compiling just fine. These are ***linker errors***, which indicates your program is not being successfully linked against `liblastfm`.

I'm assuming you're linking against `liblastfm` *binaries* that you downloaded, and not something you are building. The problem is that this library is a "C" ABI library, and you're compiling your application with g++.  That means all symbols will be [*mangled*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

The *real* problem is that the `clastfm.h` header file needs to have `extern "C"` wrapping its contents. This tells g++ to not generate external symbol referenes with mangled names for those functions, and instead use plain-old C-style (non-mangled) naming.

You could try modifying your code like this:

```
extern "C" {
#include "clastfm.h"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I realize that. I just poorly worded the question. If you look in my compilation statement, which is the third code box, `-lclastfm` is included.

Comment: I'm wondering if they're missing `extern "C"` in their header files, and g++ is mangling the names.  EDIT: They are. Try playing with `extern "C"`, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12994075/119527).

Comment: Hmm. That's a part of C I am not familiar with, but it seems like a big possibility. I tried adding it to my code, but I seem to not be using it correctly because I get this error: `expected unqualified-id before string constant
   extern "C" { LASTFM_SESSION *s; }`

Comment: Your edit to the original answer worked like a charm. Thank you, good sir. If I can ever Vote Up, I will undoubtedly come back to this question to do so.